# Java Enum Types - Self Printing Enums

Tags: java, enums

I'm trying to write a java function that takes as a parameter an enum type (part of a console based menuing system). This function will then print all of the string representations in the enum.

The enum looks like this:

```
protected enum main{
    Option1,
    Option2,
    Option3,
    ...
    OptionN,
}
```

My display function looks like this

```
public void displayMenu(Enum menu) {
     // Get values from enum type
     Enum menuOps = menu.values();

     // Iterate over values and print
     for(int i =0 ; i < menuOps.length; i++)
            System.out.println( i + menuOps[i].toString() );
}
```

My problem: Apparently I must not be doing this correctly. The "menu" parameter object doesn't have a values() method in this scenario.

The desired outcome would be the displayMenu() function having an output of:

```
Option1
Option2
Option3
...
OptionN
```

Any pointers on where I'm going wrong with this? Any tips on how to implement this functionality?

Much obliged,

Noob

Comment: What is the exact compiler error message that you're getting?

Comment: @Oli: I actually haven't compiled it yet. I'm still designing the overall solution (to my homework assignment). One of those 4a bright ideas I guess (lol). Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't quite work that way, an Enum entry doesn't know about the other entries. You have to consult the containing class:

```
for (Enum current : menu.getClass().getEnumConstants()) {
    System.out.println(current);
}
```

Here's a Generic version of the method:

```
public static <K extends Enum<K>> void displayEnumValues(final K enumItem) {
    for (final Enum<K> current : enumItem.getClass().getEnumConstants()) {
        System.out.println(current);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Because your print method is not dependend on a concreate enum instance, it should be based on a concreate enum class, not on an instance of this class

```
public static <T extends Enum<T>> void printEnum(Class<T> enumClass) {
    for (Enum<T> item : enumClass.getEnumConstants()) {
        System.out.println(item.toString());
    }
}
...
printEnum(MainEnum.class);
```

Comment: This also is a good solution. I'm a bit squeamish when it comes to generics...thanks again!

Comment: This is basically the same method as mine (just with the class as parameter, not an enum item). +1

Answer (score 1):

Migrate

```
public void displayMenu(Enum menu) {
     // Get values from enum type
     Enum menuOps = menu.values();
```

to

```
 public void displayMenu(main menu) {
     // Get values from enum type
     main[] menuOps = menu.values();
```

Comment: @Vladmir, Thanks for the reply. But if I enforce the parameter be "properly" typed (i.e. Enum menu vs main menu), this display function is limited to printing just the main menu. As a result, I'd have to both write an enum and a display function for each specific enum type (e.g. sub menu).

I wanted to just define the enum types for all menus and have (this) single function be capable of printing them all in this fashion.

Is that even possible?